# SQL Server select query very slow

Tags: sql-server

[image]I have direct table with 2 million records, while running select statement in the SQL query builder, it is very fast, but through program, it takes 35 minutes for 1100 records. I have two columns `icno` and `efpno`. These two columns have duplicate records. My table has a clustered index and one nonclustered index with `icno` and `efpno`.

Please check my query and advice.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO p_count
FROM ct_rgpldgr
WHERE ctrgp_nric = p_ctegd.ctegd_nric
  AND ctrgp_epfno = p_ctegd.ctegd_epfno
```

ctrgp_nric,ctrgp_epfno from load file. this query reading from .txt file. This nric and epf number will be inside the load file.

I run tuning adviser and execution plane but it show estimation cost `0.03`.

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: What is `p_ctegd`?

Comment: You missed something in the query while pasting here?

Comment: You're not providing much information. Go to the menu bar and select Query -> Include actual execution plan too see where the bottleneck is

Comment: ctrgp_nric,ctrgp_epfno from load file. this query reading from .txt file. This nric and epf number will be inside the load file.

Comment: Can you create an index with both keys: ctrgp_nric and ctrgp_epfno?

Comment: Never post images of code, output or errors! [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times the reason for the query being slow are full table scans. In order to find out where these full table scans happens you need to know the execution plan off your query. This can be done for example with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

You can get the estimated execution plan in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio by highlighting your query and then clicking on the following menu item:

[image]

This will display a graph like this one:

[image]

This graph has a cost estimation on each node. Especially interesting are the nodes which have a high cost like the one which is highlighted above. The nodes with a high cost indicate mostly tables where MSSQL is performing a full table scan and on which potentially you will need to add some index. After you know which tables are being fully scanned you will need to find the column on which you should build the index and that is typically a column in your query on which you are performing an inner join.

Comment: Also note that SQL Server is giving you a good hint, in green color, just above the execution plan.

Comment: @GuidoG yes, thank you very much for pointing that out. You are absolutely correct.